# WebScraping in Python with BS4 - Getting dynamically generated list

Tags: python, web-scraping, dynamic

I need to crawl the list of "Best Coding Bootcamps" present in this list:
https://www.switchup.org/rankings/best-coding-bootcamps

My assignment says this should be possible with Beautiful Soup (and not with Selenium) however when I attempt to do that the resulting HTML doesn't return the list of the bootcamps but rather what appears to be an empty element of class:

My questions is, do you think this content is possible to retrieve only with Beautiful Soup without resorting to Selenium? If Selenium is necessary, what would be a simple code to do so?

The code so far is very simple:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

import time

url = "https://www.switchup.org/rankings/best-coding-bootcamps"

r = requests.get(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
time.sleep(5)

print(soup)
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have right, the page at the URL you've posted is empty. The data is loaded through AJAX from another URL.

If you inspect the Network tab in Firefox/Chrome, you can find this URL (the data is in JSON format):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.switchup.org/chimera/v1/bootcamp-list?mainTemplate=bootcamp-list%2Frankings&path=%2Frankings%2Fbest-coding-bootcamps&isDataTarget=false&featuredSchools=0&logoTag=logo&logoSize=original&numSchools=0&perPage=0&rankType=BootcampRankings&rankYear=2020&recentReview=true&reviewLength=50&numLocations=5&numSubjects=5&numCourses=5&sortOn=name&withReviews=false'

data = requests.get(url).json()

for i, bootcamp in enumerate(data['content']['bootcamps'], 1):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(bootcamp['description'], 'html.parser')
    print('{}. {}'.format(i, bootcamp['name']))
    print(soup.get_text(strip=True))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
1. Le Wagon
Le Wagon is an intensive international coding bootcamp geared toward career changers and entrepreneurs who want to gain coding skills. Participants complete 450 hours of coding in 9 weeks full-time or 24 weeks part-time, which includes building their own web app. After completing the program, students join an international alumni network of 6,000+ for career support and community.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. App Academy
App Academy teaches participants everything they need to know about software engineering in just 12 weeks. Their full-time bootcamps have helped over 2,000 graduates find jobs at more than 850 companies. Their deferred tuition plan means participants pay for the program only after they’ve landed their first web development job.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Ironhack
Ironhack offers two full-time bootcamps focused on web design, a 26-week program in web development and a nine-week program in user experience and user interface design. Students can access extensive career development services post-graduation including portfolio building and interview practice; scholarships are available for underrepresented populations and veterans.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Comment: You can add some good columns in a dataframe as well: pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(data['content']['bootcamps'])).drop(columns=['courses', 'totalCourses', 'subjects', 'locations', 'recentReview', 'meritBadges', 'logoUrl'])

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect! I'm a beginner in this, how did you figure out that the data was being loaded through that url? when I inspect the page I see immediately all the HTML as if it were static content

Comment: @peterram In my Firefox I right-clicked on the page and saw that it doesn't contain any data. Then I looked in Network inspector and the data was there as another XHR request.